# Code analysis warning (C26426) and using RegisterWindowMessage - How to resolve?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis

Code:

```
#define UWM_TEST _T("UWM_TEST_{GUID_VALUE_HERE}")
static const UINT UWM_TEST_MSG = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_TEST);
```

The above works fine but code analysis complains:

> [C26426](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26426?view=msvc-160): Global initializer calls a non-constexpr function [`RegisterWindowMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew) (i.22).

The aforementioned states:

> The order of execution of initializers for global objects may be
> inconsistent or undefined. This can lead to issues that are hard to
> reproduce and investigate. To avoid such problems, global initializers
> should not depend on external code that's executed at run time and can
> potentially depend on data that's not yet initialized. This rule flags
> cases where global objects call functions to obtain their initial
> values.

I have looked at the examples on the linked page but I do not understand what I must do to correct this for code analysis.

---

Also logged this issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Global-initializer-calls-a-non-constexpr/1563190

Comment: Curious, so I searched while wincore.cpp was open. MFC would get this same warning it seems, line 31. How likely will it be that `UWM_TEST_MSG` would be used before it was initialized? From what I've seen, pretty unlikely if never. But, it could happen? As @Adrian Mole eludes to, is there a non global space you can code it?

Comment: @lakeweb I went with an answer addressing one of two scenarios. In the second case of my suggested answer, it is virtually impossible that the message would (or even *could*) be used before the `CWinApp`-derived object is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `UWM_TEST_MSG` message is only ever used within member functions of a particular class, then, rather than defining it as a (static) global constant, you can make it a `const` (but *not* `static`) member of that class, like so:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
private:
    #define UWM_TEST _T("UWM_TEST_{GUID_VALUE_HERE}")
    const uint32_t UWM_TEST_MSG = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_TEST);
    ///...
};
```

Otherwise (if the message is used more generally), you can make it a similar (but `public`) member of your application class:

```cpp
class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    #define UWM_TEST _T("UWM_TEST_{GUID_VALUE_HERE}")
    const uint32_t UWM_TEST_MSG = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_TEST);
    ///...
};
```

In the latter case, you will need to change all occurrences of the identifier into something like the following expression (unless, of course, it is being used inside a member of `MyApp`):

```cpp
static_cast<MyApp*>(AfxGetApp())->UWM_TEST_MSG
```

*(Alternatively, if you have an `extern MyApp theApp;` declared in your code, as MFC programs generally do, you can just use `theApp.UWM_TEST_MSG` instead of the above expression.)*

Either way, making the message a **non-static** (but still `const`) data member of the class (whichever one that is), will avoid the warning (and the potential issues it highlights), because the call to `RegisterWindowMessage` will only be made when an object of that class is instantiated.

Comment: Note that you could also define a macro to represent `static_cast<MyApp*>(AfxGetApp())->WM_DATETIME_EDIT`, or use a macro with the ID and use something else for the underlying class member's name. That would remove the need to change other, dependent parts of your code ... but folks around here don't really like macros. (There are also many people around these parts that will jump up and down, turn purple and swear at you even for using global variables!)

Comment: We can tidy up these comments. Deleted od comments now. I moved them into the application class and adjusted them as per your example. Because I have `extern CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp theApp;` all I had to do was prefix my existing instances with `theApp.`.

Comment: Alternatively, place the `static` variable inside a free function, e.g. `UINT test_msg_id() { static const UINT msg_id{ ::RegisterWindowMessage(L"...") }; return msg_id; }`, and call `test_msg_id()` whenever you need the ID. This conveniently works around the undefined order of initialization of objects with static storage duration, but you won't be able to use it like a constant (e.g. it cannot appear inside a `case` label, I think).